# Converting Comprehension List to Numpy Array - Glitch?

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy, list-comprehension

I am having trouble converting a comprehension list into a `numpy` array. I am looping through different comprehension lists; some seem to be fine though. I verified this error by printing their `shape`, and some iterations did not return the correct dimensions. As such, I cannot concatenate these numpy arrays (Ingredients) with another set of arrays (basic_info). Also, I printed the numpy array itself for these iterations, and noticed that the '[' had an extra trailing space. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Please see below:

**(1) This is how I created the list comprehension**

```
html = browser.page_source
            soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
            table = soup.find('div', {'id': 'placeBody_dynField77_divScroll'})
            table_body = table.find('tbody')
            rows = table_body.findAll('tr')[1:]
            Ingredients = []
            for row in rows:
                cols = row.find_all('td')
                cols = [ele.text.strip() for ele in cols]
                Ingredients.append([ele for ele in cols if ele])
            Ingredients = np.array(Ingredients)
```

**(2) Upon printing the `shape`, the number of columns is not returned (which should be 8)**

```
print(Ingredients)
print(Ingredients.shape, basic_info2.shape)

>>

[ ['Distillates (Petroleum), Hydrotreated Heavy Naphthenic', '64742-52-5', 'n/a', '40.00 %', '50.00 %', '45.00 %', '40-<50%', '0.00 %']
 ['2-(2-butoxyéthoxy) Éthanol', '112-34-5', 'n/a', '10.00 %', '20.00 %', '15.00 %', '10-<20%', '0.00 %']
 ['Low Odor Base Solvent', '64742-47-8', 'n/a', '10.00 %', '20.00 %', '15.00 %', '10-<20%', '0.00 %']
 ['Other Components Below Reportable Levels', 'n/a', '5.00 %', '10.00 %', '7.50 %', '5-<10%', '0.00 %']
 ['Naphtha (Petroleum), Hydrotreated, Heavy', '64742-48-9', 'n/a', '5.00 %', '10.00 %', '7.50 %', '5-<10%', '0.00 %']
 ['Solvent Naphtha (Petroleum), Medium Aliph.', '64742-88-7', 'n/a', '5.00 %', '10.00 %', '7.50 %', '5-<10%', '0.00 %']
 ['Stoddard Solvent', '8052-41-3', 'n/a', '5.00 %', '10.00 %', '7.50 %', '5-<10%', '0.00 %']
 ['Carbon Dioxide', '124-38-9', 'n/a', '1.00 %', '3.00 %', '2.00 %', '1-<3%', '0.00 %']
 ['Nonane', '111-84-2', 'Less Than (Max)', '0.00 %', '1.00 %', '0.50 %', '<1%', '0.00 %']
 ['Naphthalene', '91-20-3', 'Less Than (Max)', '0.00 %', '1.00 %', '0.50 %', '<1%', '0.00 %']]
[(10,), (10, 4)]
[ ['Gasoline, Low Boiling Point Naphtha', '86290-81-5', 'n/a', '90.00 %', '100.00 %', '95.00 %', '90.00-100.00%', '0.00 %']
 ['EthylBenzene', '100-41-4', 'Blank (percentage not specified)', '0.00 %', '100.00 %', '50.00 %', '0.00 %']
 ['Toluene', '108-88-3', 'Blank (percentage not specified)', '0.00 %', '100.00 %', '50.00 %', '0.00 %']
 ['N-Hexane', '110-54-3', 'Blank (percentage not specified)', '0.00 %', '100.00 %', '50.00 %', '0.00 %']
 ['Cyclohexane', '110-82-7', 'Blank (percentage not specified)', '0.00 %', '100.00 %', '50.00 %', '0.00 %']
 ['Xylene (Mixed Isomers)', '1330-20-7', 'Blank (percentage not specified)', '0.00 %', '100.00 %', '50.00 %', '0.00 %']
 ['Trimethylbenzene. All Isomers', '25551-13-7', 'Blank (percentage not specified)', '0.00 %', '100.00 %', '50.00 %', '0.00 %']
 ['Benzene', '71-43-2', 'Blank (percentage not specified)', '0.00 %', '100.00 %', '50.00 %', '0.00 %']
 ['Naphthalene', '91-20-3', 'Blank (percentage not specified)', '0.00 %', '100.00 %', '50.00 %', '0.00 %']]
[(9,), (9, 4)]
```

Answer (score 2):

numpy doesn't support ragged arrays (arrays where not every row has the same length).  Your `Ingredients` seems to be ragged:

```
>>> [len(x) for x in Ingredients]
[8, 8, 8, 7, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8]
```

Since numpy doesn't support this, it does the best it can and gives you an array of length 10 of object dtype.  That is, instead of having an array 10x8, you get an array of shape 10 where each element is just one object (which happens to be a Python list, but numpy no longer cares at this point).

You'll need to make the array rectangular before numpy sees it, whether by fixing your processing or by padding or adding dummy values, whatever seems appropriate.

Note though that numpy isn't really intended for dealing with tabular data of mixed type: for that, you probably want to be using [`pandas`](http://pandas.pydata.org).